# Scala Add elements to set only by checking specific fields of a case class

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections

I have a case class

```
case class ApiCall(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: String, e: String, f: String)
```

I also have a mutable Set: `private var apiCalls: mutable.Set[ApiCall] = mutable.Set[ApiCall]()`

The problem is, I may get the following `ApiCall` elements:

```
ApiCall(a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1)
ApiCall(a1, b1, c1, d2, e2, f2)
```

I have to add elements to the set only if a unique combination of `(a, b, c)` of the `case class ApiCall` doesn't already exist. I cannot modify the case class itself because it is being used in multiple places.

Is it possible to add case class elements to the set only by looking at certain fields, and not all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of solved it using a small workaround:

`private var _apiCalls: mutable.Set[ApiCall] = mutable.Set[ApiCall]()` is my Set of `ApiCall`s

I wrote a function which will add to set only if there's no 3 part key `(a, b, c)` already existing in the Set:

```
def addApiCall(e: X): Unit = {
     val m = _x.find(m => m.a == e.a && m.b == e.b && m.c == e.c)
     if (m.isEmpty)
         _x += e
}
```

I'm not going to have too many elements in the `Set` either, so I found this approach easier to handle for me..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `Map` instead of `Set` in your case:

```scala
val apiCalls = mutable.Map[(String, String, String), ApiCall]()
```

Also values are replaced for matching keys inside `Map`, you might need a separate method to update the API calls map:

```scala
def updateApiCalls(call: ApiCall): Unit = {
  apiCalls.getOrElseUpdate((call.a, call.b, call.c), call)
  ()
}
```

Comment: If an event (based on that three part key) already exists, then I dont want to update it. Instead it should be discarded..